# Good looking graphics in C# window form

Tags: c#, graphics

I need to create some simple graphics in a windows form using C#. By simple I mean lines, circles etc. However, when I draw e.g. a filled circle, the edge is not smooth (as expected when drawing a circle using square pixels), but when drawing the same circle with the same number of pixels in a vector program it looks perfect. I have been drawing in Inkscape for this example.

Maybe the vector software uses some sort of render function to smooth the colors, but is this possible in C# without creating too much code? Here is an example of the code, which is using `Graphics` to create a canvas to draw on.

```
private void StatGraphicsPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   Graphics canvas = e.Graphics;
   Brush brush = Brushes.Aqua;
   canvas.FillEllipse(brush, 0, 0, 10, 10);
}
```

**Solution**
This code does the trick:

```
private void StatGraphicsPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   Graphics canvas = e.Graphics;
   canvas.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
   Brush brush = Brushes.Aqua;
   canvas.FillEllipse(brush, 0, 0, 10, 10);
}
```

Comment: Show some code or we can't help you.

Comment: I'd go with [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation), not WinForms...

Comment: try searching in the documentaation if your graphics objects have some antialiasing property if they have set it to true

Comment: "(as expected when drawing a circle using square pixels)" All shapes are made of pixels regardless of what programming language you use. You need to increase the resolution of your shape. That or show me the code.

Comment: You get good looking graphics from a program like Photoshop.  From a designer, not a programmer.

Comment: @FabioMarcolini: You provided the search word I needed. Using the AntiAlias smooting mode on the canvas did the trick. I have updated the code. Thanks

Comment: @rasole You shouldn't update your question with the solution. You should simply mark my answer as the solution if it is.

Comment: @rasole no problem, I was sure you was looking for antialiasing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use the [`System.Drawing.Graphics.SmoothingMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.smoothingmode.aspx) property. Before beginning to use your `Graphics` object, do this:

```
canvas.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
```

That should give you a nice anti-aliased ellipse instead of the default jaggy one.

Similarly, if you want to draw high-quality text in an image, use the [`System.Drawing.Graphics.TextRenderingHint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.textrenderinghint.aspx) property.

---

As others have mentioned in comments, you might want to consider using WPF instead. WinForms are dated.

Comment: Although setting `SmoothingMode` to `HighQuality` (or `AntiAlias`)  can cause a drag on performance...

Comment: @Timothy Shields: I just added the solution before your post, but this does the trick perfectly. Performance is not an issue here. Thanks anyway.