# Set custom width for each column in a Chart

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

In a Windows form application, I want to set a custom width for each column. For example from x = 1 to x = 3 and the y = 1.

this is what i did

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Time";
chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Busy";
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;
this.chart1.Series["ServerBusyTime"].Points.AddXY(2, 10);
this.chart1.Series["ServerBusyTime"].Points.AddXY(1, 5);
this.chart1.Series["ServerBusyTime"].Points.AddXY(3, 5);
this.chart1.Series["ServerBusyTime"].Points.AddXY(4, 5);
```

The result is this :

[image: chart 1]

And this is what I'd want :

[image: chart 2]

Comment: Please provide more context. Source code snips and your display environment/name of your chart package will help.

Comment: Thanks, @zod101. Is this Excel?

OK, saw your latest add.

Comment: No , Microsoft visual studio windows form project.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add one

```
[..].AddXY(x,1)
```

for each of the x values you want to add to the chart

```
for (var i1 = 2; i < 6; i++)
   this.chart1.Series["ServerBusyTime"].Points.AddXY(i1, 1);
for (var i2 = 10; i < 20; i++)
   this.chart1.Series["ServerBusyTime"].Points.AddXY(i2, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you  but i didn't get the expected result here is the output https://ibb.co/g5CBJ6

Comment: If you mean that the boxes should be solid and the boxes should cover the area between the hour marks then a Graph library will not help you. Instead, you must rely on a pure graphics library and draw your own shapes and lines.

In Windows Forms, your chioce would be a PictureBox and a Graphics canvas. Example code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222990/good-looking-graphics-in-c-sharp-window-form